# For a group homomorphism, does there exist a subgroup of the domain isomorphic to the image?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\phi : G \to H$ be a group homomorphism. Is is it true that, there exists a subgroup $K$ of $G$ such that $K$ is isomorphic to the image of $\phi$?

Edit: How about for finite $G$?

Comment: The most that you can say is that there is a quotient group of $ G $ that is isomorphic to $ \text{Im}(\phi) $. This is the First Isomorphism Theorem for Groups.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT: $\Bbb Z$ has finite homomorphic images of all sizes; does it have finite subgroups of all sizes?

Comment: Hmm, how about when $G$ is finite?

Comment: The quaternions $Q$ have a normal subgroup $H$ such that $G/H$ is not isomorphic to a subgroup of $Q$, so the quotient map $Q \to Q/H$ is a counterexample in the finite case.

Answer (score 0):

Not for group homomorphisms, but if you have $\mathbb{C}G$-modules $V$ and $W$ and any $\mathbb{C}G$-homomorphism $\phi:V\rightarrow W$, then $\exists$ a $\mathbb{C}G$-submodule $U$ of $V$ such that $V=\text{ker}\phi\oplus U$ and $U\cong \text{im}\phi$.

Answer (score 0):

No, not even if $G$ is finite.

For example, if $Q$ is the Quaternion group of order $8$ then its centre $Z(Q)$ has order $2$ and $Q/Z(Q)$ is isomorphic to the Klein $4$-group $V_4$. However, $Q$ contains no subgroup isomorphic to $V_4$.